# JavaScript Function Calls

Tags: javascript, function, onclick

Outer, Inner and Filter are DIVs, Outer contains Inner and filter is independent.

The button to execute the close function is located inside inner div. Onclicking the button, the function is not executed but when executed from the address bar, it executes

ie javascript:close(); executed in the address bar works fine. How to make this work, Whats the error ?? Have spent hours on this

```
<script type=text/javascript>
function close() {
  var x = document.getElementById("outer") ;
  var y = document.getElementById("inner") ;
  var z = document.getElementById("filter");    
  x.style.height = "0px" ;
  y.style.height = "0px";
  z.style.height = "0px";
  x.style.overflow = "hidden";
}
</script>

<div id="filter"></div>

<div id="outer"> 
  <div id="inner">
    <button onclick="close()">Close</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: There's an extra space in your "filter" `div`, is this in your original code or is it a typo?

Comment: Ahh..see that... before I could edit my question, your comment came in...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works now: http://jsfiddle.net/ckrxV/

Problem was with the name "close" which is already defined in javascript

```
function close1() {
var x = document.getElementById('outer');
var y = document.getElementById('inner');
var z = document.getElementById('filter');
alert('worked');
x.style.height = "0px";
y.style.height = "0px";
z.style.height = "0px";
x.style.overflow = "hidden";
}​
```

Answer (score 4):

rename your `close()` and your `function close()` to something like `closeme()`. <strike>Close is a reserved word</strike> See comments from `xiaoyi`

[See this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xA73g/1/)

Comment: `close` is not a reserved word, just happen to be used by `window` while `window` happens to be the scope of his code.

Comment: Thank you bart... its lack of beer causing abberations.. where I live, alchol has been recently outlawed..

Comment: You can happily overwrite this browser method, at least in Chrome (tested)

Comment: @user1812787 It also works if you put `function close()` to another scope, and binding the event to the button in that scope. [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/xA73g/2/)